# Yii2 Gridview filter by permission

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, yii2-model

I have a super admin, that can create users and can assign specific locations for each user. This is stored in a simple table, where we get the ID of the user and the ID of the location.

Then, I have a table of clients. Each client also has a location, named loc_id. How can I filter so that in the Gridview a user can only see the clients that live in a location that the user has a permission to view (a user is a kind of admin that can manipulate the data of a client in their jurisdiction)?

I get the user id by

```
$userId = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id
```

and then find the locations that he can view with

```
$userLocation = Userlocations::find()-where(['user_id' => $userId])->all();
```

But now how can I apply this to a standard Gridview with a Search Model and a DataProvider, so that I can still filter and sort the GridView by the other properties?

```
$searchModel = new AsociatiiSearch();
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First inside your AsociatiiSearch class you need to add a public attribute:

```
class AsociatiiSearch {
    public $userLocation;
    ...
```

Then inside your controller action you find the userLocation:

```
$userId = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id
$userLocation = Userlocations::find()-where(['user_id' => $userId])->all();
$searchModel = new AsociatiiSearch();
$searchModel->userLocation = $userLocation;

$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
return $this->render('index', [
    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
]);
```

Finally, on AsociatiiSearch search method you can just add another filter using the global userLocation:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['userLocation' => $this->userLocation]);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer, the idea is good I think but it gives me a blank page with only the title, even the layout doesn't load. The $userLocation = Userlocations::find()-where(['user_id' => $userId])->all(); line returns an array of objects, I think that $query->andFilterWhere(['userLocation' => $this->userLocation]) doesn't like that format. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Ok, I solved it, thanks, your answer helped me very much. First i had to make a simple array out of $userLocation and then I used $query->andFilterWhere(['IN', 'loc_id', $this->userLocation]).